# Rails migrations with postgres generated columns, failing to run in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a migration that contains a bunch of [postgres generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-generated-columns.html). This migrates fine in the production/development environment, yet errors when attempting to run tests.

The migration:

```
execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE sorns
      ADD COLUMN agency_names_tsvector tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english', coalesce(sorns.agency_names, ''))) STORED,
...
```

Running the migration creates the schema.rb like:

```
t.tsvector "agency_names_tsvector", default: -> { "to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(agency_names, ''::character varying))::text)" }
```

When attempting to run the tests, it errors:

```
Caused by:
PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
LINE 1: ...FAULT to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (COALESCE(agency_nam...
```

I can fix this by switching to using a structure.sql instead of schema.rb by including this line in my application.rb or even just in my enironments/test.rb file. I'd like to keep my environments equal though.
`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`

My question is why does it work in development as written in the schema.rb file, but will not migrate in the test enviroment?

Comment: Without viewing your test set up I would say it is because in `test` it is loading the schema instead of running migrations (and that is ok) the migration is not a standard one `add_column :foo, :bar` so schema loading doesn't know how to run that

Comment: It works in development because you've never run db:schema:load in development :) db:schema:load is being used in test whereas in development you've created the db structure migration after migration.

Comment: I see -- nonstandard so the TSVECTOR is not captured fully in the Rails db-agnostic schema.rb, so switch to platform-specific SQL format.

Comment: I had this same problem and yes @alediaferia was correct you need to not schema load even though it was the suggested action in the trace. I solved it by trashing my test db and manually running migrations for the test environment.
If you want the overkill method of solving, first drop your test db then:
`bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test` then
`bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`